# Access azure redis cache behind a proxy

Tags: node.js, azure, redis

From development environment, developpers need to access Redis cache.
Connection to the Azure Redis Cache is done via socks protocol on port 6380.

Issue is that external access to the internet is done via a proxy in our company.

If it's HTTP(S) access, in nodejs for example, we use npm package 'dotenv' where we specify 'HTTP(S)' proxy settings (example for package ms-rest azure).

But here we don't find any solutions to for proxy usage for socks access.

We use the npm package 'redis' in that case.

Does anyone have a solution to for proxy usage?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be impossible for directly connecting to Azure Redis Cache from a client behind a proxy. The reason as below:

1. Redis only supports tcp connection via its protocol like `telnet`, it's infeasible if your proxy does not support `socks`.
2. After I searched two recommended NodeJS redis clients `ioredis` & `node_redis`, both don't support build connection via proxy.

So here are two possible solutions for your current scenario.

1. If your proxy supports `socks`, you can try to create a new redis client via change some code based on the existing redis client to support socks proxy.
2. Recommended for the current case. I suggest that you can create a HTTP service on Azure to handle the requests from your client behind your proxy, which can pass the parameters of HTTP requests to Azure Redis Cache and wrap the result into the HTTP responses. It's Redis over HTTP like [`solutious/bone`](https://github.com/solutious/bone).

Hope it helps.